# Get instance of a class using generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a game that uses MVCS and has, so far, clearly separated the business logic from the view.

However, I've been having trouble with one particular piece of the puzzle.

In the game we have command classes (`IPlayerCommand`) that execute a specific business logic. Each command class returns a result class (`PlayerCommandResult`). For each `PlayerCommand` we have a respected visual command class (`IVisualPlayerCommand`) that takes the `PlayerCommandResult` and updates the view accordingly.

I'd like the `IVisualPlayerCommand` to use specific classes that inherit `PlayerCommandResult` in order to get the information it needs (as opposed to using `object`). I'd also like to make it compile-time safe (as opposed to casting it before using it). For these two reasons I made the classes use generics.

Here are the declaration of the classes:

```
public class PlayerCommandResult
{}

public interface IPlayerCommand<T> where T : PlayerCommandResult
{
    T Execute(GameWorld world);
}

public interface IVisualPlayerComamnd<T> where T : PlayerCommandResult
{
    void Play(T commandResult);
}
```

Here is the Move Unit command as an example:

```
public class MoveUnitPlayerCommand : IPlayerCommand<MoveUnitPlayerCommandResult>
{
    private Unit unitToMove;

    public MoveUnitPlayerCommand(Unit unit)
    {
        this.unitToMove = unit;
    }

    public MoveUnitPlayerCommandResult Execute(GameWorld world)
    {
        MoveUnitPlayerCommand result = new MoveUnitPlayerCommand();
        // Do some changes to the world and store any information needed to the result
        return result;
    }
}

public class MoveUnitVisualPlayerCommand : IVisualPlayerCommand<MoveUnitPlayerCommandResult>
{
    void Play(MoveUnitPlayerCommandResult commandResult)
    {
        // Do something visual
    }
}

public class MoveUnitPlayerCommandResult : PlayerCommandResult
{
    public Unit TargetUnit { get; private set; }
    public Path MovePath { get; private set; }
}
```

So far, so good. However, I'm having a really hard time tying a `IPlayerCommand` to a `IVisualPlayerCommand` because of the use of generics:

```
public class CommandExecutorService
{
    public void ExecuteCommand<T>(IPlayerCommand<T> command) where T : PlayerCommandResult
    {
        T result = command.Execute(world);
        IVisualPlayerCommand<T> visualCommand = GetVisualPlayerCommand(command);
        visualCommand.Play(result);
    }

    public IVisualPlayerCommand<T> GetVisualPlayerCommand<T>(IPlayerCommand<T> command) where T : PlayerCommandResult
    {
        // ?!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!??!?!
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that what I'm trying to do is not even possible because of the way generics work in C# (as opposed to Java where I could say IVisualPlayerCommand<**?**>).

Could you help me figure out a way?

Any feedback for the design is welcome.

P.S. Sorry if the title doesn't reflect the question. I wasn't sure how to boil down the question in one line.
P.P.S. Which is why I also don't know if this question has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You two command classes, are served as service. To me, for this case, I would use the service locator pattern. As how to implement this pattern, you can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx)

The drawback of using template, is that, if something changes, you have to compiled it again.

Here's [link](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/09/25/service-locator-pattern-in-csharpa-simple-example/) which provides an example of the service locator pattern.

So for you code, you want find the corresponding instance of IVisualPlayerCommand to IPlayerCommand, so the concrete service can inherit from both interface, which it actually implements the  IVisualPlayerCommand interface, while the IPlayerCommand just severs as a tag.

so the code will like this:

```
class MoveUnitVisualPlayerCommand: IVisualPlayerCommand, IPlayerCommand {} 
services = new Dictionary<object, object>();
this.services.Add(typeof(IPlayerCommand ), new MoveUnitVisualPlayerCommand());
```

as how to get the service, you can refer the example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I should have a concrete CommandExecutor for every command as well? Aren't those classes going to contain the exact same method just with different types?

Comment: No, CommandExcutor should be just one. Those classes should inherit from the same service interface, with different implementations, as I think.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask if you could write an example in pastebin? It doesn't have to compile. I just need to get an idea of what you are thinking. Thanks.

Comment: BINGO! I already use Dependency Injection, so the service locator wasn't necessary. However, I was missing the Dictionary<object, object> bit and the casting. I was so obsessed of not casting, I forgot that I tried to find a way to use generics everywhere. Thanks!